How Does One Verify This Operator Norm Inequality?
I am looking at the following problem from a functional analysis book, and unsure how they arrive at this conclusion:

Let $H,L$ be Hilbert spaces and $A$ a $C^{*}$-algebra with $\pi_H: A \longrightarrow B(H)$ and $\pi_L: A \longrightarrow B(L)$ faithful non-degenerate $*$-representations, and moreover assume $\pi_H$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $\xi_0 \in H$.  Let $u \in B(H \otimes L)$ be the unitary charicterized by $$u(\pi_H(a)\xi_0 \otimes \eta) = (\pi_H \otimes \pi_L)(\Phi(a))(\xi_0 \otimes \eta)$$ where $\Phi: A \longrightarrow A \otimes A$ is a $*$-homomorphism.
Now, approximate $\Phi(a) \approx \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i$ in $A \otimes A$ and let $\theta_{\xi_1,\pi_{H}(a)\xi_0} \in B(H)$ by $\theta_{\xi_1,\pi_{H}(a)\xi_0}: \xi \mapsto \langle \xi,\xi_1 \rangle \pi_H(a)\xi_0$.  Then we have: $$\left\lVert u\left(\theta_{\xi_1,\pi_{H}(a)\xi_0} \otimes 1_{L} \right) - \sum_{i} \theta_{\xi_1,\pi_H(b_i)\xi_0} \otimes \pi_L(c_i) \right\rVert \leq \left\lVert \xi_1 \right\rVert \left\lVert \xi_0 \right\rVert  \left\lVert \Phi(a) - \sum_{i} b_i \otimes c_i \right\rVert.$$

This looks like alot of moving parts, but the only thing this is really coming down to is that I can't just apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality like I want to.  First, it suffices to check that the above equality holds on $H \odot L$, so let $\sum_{k} \xi'_k \otimes \eta_k \in H \odot L$.  Then: $$\left\lVert u\left(\theta_{\xi_1,\pi_{H}(a)\xi_0} \otimes 1_{L} \right)\left(\sum_{k} \xi'_k \otimes \eta_k \right) - \sum_{i} \theta_{\xi_1,\pi_H(b_i)\xi_0} \otimes \pi_L(c_i) \left( \sum_k \xi'_k \otimes \eta_k\right) \right\rVert $$ $$\leq \sum_k |\langle \xi'_k,\xi_1 \rangle| \left\lVert (\pi_H \otimes \pi_L)(\Phi(a))(\xi_0 \otimes \eta_k) - \sum_i (\pi_H \otimes \pi_L)(b_i \otimes c_i)(\xi_0 \otimes \eta_k) \right\rVert$$ $$= \sum_k |\langle \xi'_k,\xi_1 \rangle| \left\lVert (\pi_H \otimes \pi_L)\left(\Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i \right)(\xi_0 \otimes \eta_k) \right\rVert$$ $$\leq \lVert \xi_0 \rVert \left\lVert \Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i \right\rVert\sum_k |\langle \xi'_k,\xi_1 \rangle| \lVert \eta_k \rVert $$ $$\leq \lVert \xi_0 \rVert \lVert \xi_1 \rVert \left\lVert \Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i \right\rVert\sum_k \lVert\xi'_k \rVert \lVert \eta_k \rVert$$ $$ \leq \lVert \xi_0 \rVert \lVert \xi_1 \rVert \left\lVert \Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i \right\rVert \left(\sum_k \lVert \xi'_k \rVert^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_j \lVert \eta_j \rVert^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$  However we have on the other hand that: $$\left\lVert \sum_k \xi'_k \otimes \eta_k \right\rVert^2 = \sum_{k,j} \langle \xi'_k,\xi'_j \rangle \langle \eta_k,\eta_j \rangle \geq \sum_k \lVert \xi'_k \rVert^2 \lVert \eta_k \rVert^2$$ $$\implies \left\lVert \sum_k \xi'_k \otimes \eta_k \right\rVert \geq \left( \sum_k \lVert \xi'_k \rVert^2 \lVert \eta_k \rVert^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ which isn't quite the same thing.  I am just running into the inequality that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1 \leq \sqrt{n} \lVert \cdot \rVert_2$.  I also tried expaning this with inner products (which is the more natural thing to immediately try ofcourse), but again I don't seem to get anywhere.  I just end up with a mess of terms and again want to apply the CSI (for inner products), which has again led me to get an overestimation.

You just moved $\sum_k$ and $|\langle \xi’_k, \xi_1 \rangle|$ outside of the norm too early, is all. If you had kept them inside the norm, without applying triangle inequality first, you would have obtained,
$$\text{LHS} \leq \|\xi_0\|\left\|\Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i\right\|\left\|\sum_k \langle \xi_k’, \xi_1 \rangle \eta_k\right\|$$
Now, we have,
$$\begin{split}
\left\|\sum_k \langle \xi_k’, \xi_1 \rangle \eta_k\right\| &= \sup_{\eta’ \in L, \|\eta’\| = 1} \left|\sum_k \langle \xi’_k, \xi_1 \rangle \langle \eta_k, \eta’ \rangle\right|\\
&= \sup_{\eta’ \in L, \|\eta’\| = 1} \left|\left\langle \sum_k \xi’_k \otimes \eta_k, \xi_1 \otimes \eta’ \right\rangle \right|\\
&\leq \sup_{\eta’ \in L, \|\eta’\| = 1} \left\|\sum_k \xi’_k \otimes \eta_k\right\|\|\xi_1\|\|\eta’\|\\
&= \left\|\sum_k \xi’_k \otimes \eta_k\right\|\|\xi_1\|
\end{split}$$
Thus,
$$\text{LHS} \leq \|\xi_0\|\|\xi_1\|\left\|\Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i\right\| \left\|\sum_k \xi’_k \otimes \eta_k\right\|$$

Ahh yeah oops, I think the amount of notation tripped me up, but its literally just $\lVert T(\xi_0 \otimes \sum_k \langle \xi'_k,\xi_1 \rangle \eta_k) \rVert$ where $T = (\pi_H \otimes \pi_L)(\Phi(a) - \sum_i b_i \otimes c_i)$.

@Isochron Yeah. There are too many summations floating around, so it’s quite natural to want to move one of the summations outside early, which caused the problem. Setting $T$ like that is probably a good idea to clarify what’s going on.
